# How can I not hide all ul in navbar, under button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I learn `bootstrap` and attemp responsive page as `apple main page` *(sorry, I can`t post more two links)*
In header all element hiden under button, except for apple and bag.

[big header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r63e.png)

[small header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In3KU.png)

In small size of page, button is left, apple is center and bag is right. 
And under button are all element, except for apple and bag. How can I this result get?
My code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>   
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/apple/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/mac/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/ipad/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/iphone/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/watch/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/tv/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/music/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/links/support/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/search/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/bag/image_large.svg"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

and default bootstrap.css

Comment: Whatever you don't want to hide should not be in the collapsed div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your `navbar-header` element as follows :

```
<!-- Add a text-center class to handle centering your Apple logo -->
<div class="navbar-header text-center">
    <!-- Add your Apple logo (only seen on extra-small viewports) -->
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/apple/image_large.svg"></a>
    <!-- Add your last "shopping" icon to the right (via pull-right) -->
    <a class='pull-right visible-xs' href="#"><img src="http://www.apple.com/ac/globalnav/2.0/en_US/images/ac-globalnav/globalnav/bag/image_large.svg"></a>
    <!-- Add the pull-left style to your button to left-align it -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>   
</div>
```

Then add the following styles to adjust those as necessary to your custom CSS :

```
/* Absolutely center your logo over the header */
.navbar-brand { float: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 100vw;  padding: 0}
/* Set the default display option to cause it to be centered */
.navbar-brand img { display: initial; }
/* Add a left margin to your now left-aligned toggle button */
.navbar-toggle.pull-left { margin-left: 10px;}
/* Do the same for your right-aligned shopping link */
a.pull-right { margin-right: 10px;}
```

**Example**

You can [see an example of this here](http://jsbin.com/hocobo/3/edit?html,css,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: Apparently the order the items appear can have an effect on Bootstrap's toggle functionality. It should [work in the updated example](http://jsbin.com/hocobo/edit?html,css,output). I've updated the code / example accordingly.